# How to sort an array of objects and display in Table View in iOS Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios10.3, xcode8

Im working on displaying json data in table view and passing table view data to next view controller. Here i want to sort my json response based on name and then display in table view. here is my json data

```
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "597323707c691a6b27c63bcc",
        "name": "Adidas",
        "file": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717927565.jpg",
        "logo": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717910702.jpg",     
    },
    {
        "_id": "597323707c691a6b27c63bcc",
        "name": "Bibo",
        "file": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717927565.jpg",
        "logo": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717910702.jpg",     
    }, {
        "_id": "597323707c691a6b27c63bcc",
        "name": "Caprese",
        "file": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717927565.jpg",
        "logo": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717910702.jpg",     
    }, {
        "_id": "597323707c691a6b27c63bcc",
        "name": "DK",
        "file": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717927565.jpg",
        "logo": "http://104.236.67.117:5000/uploads/1500717910702.jpg",     
    }
```

i am able to sort only name but not the whole object. Can any one solve this issue for me? It will be very helpful for me... thanks in advance.....

Comment: Use NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: but i want to sort objects of array in the response

Comment: i am using this line to sort the json data     sortedArray = [serverData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];      here i am only able to sort single element. But question is how to sort total objects in an array

Comment: use "caseInsensitiveCompare:" instead of "localizedCaseInsensitiveC‌​ompare:"

Comment: *********-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance********                 how can i solve this issue

Comment: Could you show me your sort descriptorCode

Comment: NSIndexSet* indexes = [sortedArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                    return [string rangeOfString:[brandsIndexTitles objectAtIndex:i] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSAnchoredSearch].location != NSNotFound;                   to display sorted array in table view in alphabetical order

Comment: In above question you asked about sorting an array. But here in this code you had taken NSIndexSet. Whats your exact need.

Comment: i have already sorted my json data by the code which you have given now my question is when i tap on an alphabet like (when i tap on R) then it has to be moved to particular strings in the list ????

Comment: like iPhone contacts screen?

Comment: yeah absolutely...

Comment: Up to now I didn't implement this. I don't know how to do that. But your error says "Your trying to get the value which is not exist". may be indexPath:i is wrong.

Comment: If you are unable to fix that issue. Send mail to me "phani697@gmail.com".

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [arr sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

change it to swift code. Its working. I check this code with NSDictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

in Objective C:(answer of user3306145)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES];

NSArray *sortedArray = [self.displayItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score -1):

var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

Comment: Please provide an Objective C code snippet for the problem. The OP has tagged it objective-c.